# Person creating a record ends up NOT being the creator (CreateBy) of that record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

CRM is acting different latety. My problem is the following:

When people creating records (custom entity) they are automatically the owner of this record, as it should be in these cases. Plug-ins are fired.

Strangely the person who created the record is not the person shown in the "CreatedBy" field. The person in the "CreatedBy" field seems to be randomly chosen because if differs all the time.

The record are created via ISV-aspx pages. The connection is established via Windows authentication (CRM2011 On-premise).

Example:
A user, say "Peter" enters a record in the timesheet entity and saves the record. A plug-in fires (in pre-mode) and adds a few default fields. After saving the record the form is showing Peter as the owner and Marion as the creator.

Anybody?

Thanks,
Martin de Bont

Answer (score 0):

Are your ISV pages caching authentication by chance? It could be that "Marion's" credentials were cached when Peter entered the record. In this case, the cached credentials would be used to create the record even though "Peter" was logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a record without the ISV pages and run the browser by using `CTRl+SHIFT+P` command in `IE`. It will open the browser in a private window where caching won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. Some time ago in the middle of the night I woke up and knew the solution to my problem.

The problems started after I released an update in which I made changes to a routine returning a IOrganizationService object. I created a singleton for this matter. So if someone requested this object he or she received the object which was possibly already created by someone else.